# How to send multipart/form file from base64 Python

Tags: python, python-requests, base64, multipartform-data

How to send base64 image using multipart form data in Python?

I use a requests module, and read base64 string from file

I need to send image by multipart form, but this file is base64 decoded. How to solve it?

This code does not send file... :(

```py
# base64 file /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...
ref_path = open("template.txt", "r")
image = ref_path.read()

decoded_image = base64.b64decode(image)

url = "https://example.com"

headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = {
    'file1': decoded_image
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

print(json.loads(r.text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example for a test file & test url which just dumps passed data.

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from pprint import pprint

import requests

iamge = open("template.txt", "r").read()
decoded_image = base64.b64decode(iamge)

files = {
    'file1': ('test file.csv', BytesIO(decoded_image))
}

r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", files=files)
pprint(r.json())

print('++++++++++ Body debug ++++++++++')
print(r.request.body.decode())
```

Outputs

```
# > python test.py
{'args': {},
 'data': '',
 'files': {'file1': 'How to send base64 image using multipart form data in '
                    'Python?\n'
                    '\n'
                    'I use a requests module, and read base64 string from '
                    'file\n'
                    '\n'
                    'I need to send image by multipart form, but this file is '
                    'base64 decoded. How to solve it?\n'
                    '\n'
                    'This code does not send file... :('},
 'form': {},
 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
             'Content-Length': '397',
             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; '
                             'boundary=ea195eaa1aa183b4b32cc5c125ee0b64',
             'Host': 'httpbin.org',
             'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0'},
 'json': None,
 'origin': '188.85.244.205, 188.85.244.205',
 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/post'}
++++++++++ Body debug ++++++++++
--ea195eaa1aa183b4b32cc5c125ee0b64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="test file.csv"

How to send base64 image using multipart form data in Python?

I use a requests module, and read base64 string from file

I need to send image by multipart form, but this file is base64 decoded. How to solve it?

This code does not send file... :(
--ea195eaa1aa183b4b32cc5c125ee0b64--
```

> You shouldn't pass `headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}` because files upload also requires `boundary=xxxxx` for splitting POST body to named sequence.

Comment: But I need to give a name to my file. Now your response has form: { }

I need to get code, working like this html form

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="http://example.com" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Check my modified answer version

Comment: and now, added some debug info for the generated body and how to pass a file name in the request example

Comment: What's the point of BytesIO? Don't you already have the byte data decoded?